Passing keys to \lenest:nn
Is it possible to pass keys to \lenes:nn ?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lenes:nn
  {

    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {mig}
          { \geometry { paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm, #2 } }
      }
  }

\dim_new:N  \l_lenes_left_dim
\dim_new:N  \l_lenes_right_dim

\keys_define:nn { kvi_lenes }
  {
    left .dim_set:N = \l_lenes_left_dim,
    left .initial:n = 21pt,
    left .default:n = 21pt,
    left .value_required:n = false,
    left .usage = general,

    right .dim_set:N = \l_lenes_right_dim,
    right .initial:n = 13pt,
    right .default:n = 13pt,
    right .value_required:n = false,
    right .usage = general,
  }


\NewDocumentCommand {\lenes} { m O{} }
  { 
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_lenes} {#2}
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {mig} { \lenes:nn {mig, #2} }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lenes {mig} [left=21pt, right=13pt]

\end{document}


please post a sensible example. The code posted just stops with undefined command \lenest.

Now it just stops with undefined command \lenes:n  please post an example related to your question,

you have defined \lenes:nn to take two arguments so obviously it needs \lenes:nn {mig}{#2} just basic tex syntax unrelated to any specifics of the question.

Why not use @DavidCarlisle's answer to your earlier question about this? All you are doing here is setting up some pre-defined groups of settings and allowing them to be overridden and passing the lot to \geometry. Since \geometry can already handle the options, the pre-defined groups are all there is to do. You're adding a bunch of processing to no purpose. (That is, I'm sure you have a purpose, but it isn't apparent what it is.)

You should know that geometry sometimes behaves strangely if you set and then override settings. This doesn't usually happen, but it can. It's much less problematic to just set the keys you want in the first place. For that reason, setting a bunch of defaults probably isn't a great idea. Better let the user decide what they need in the first place.

This is basic tex syntax. If you define
\def\foo#1#2{...}

The syntax to use the command is \foo{a}{b} not \foo{a,b}.
You have defined \lenest:nn to have two arguments (as shown by the :nn in its name in L3 syntax) so the call should be
\lenes:nn {mig}{#2}  not \lenes:nn {mig, #2}
As you have it,
#1 is mig,left=21pt, right=13pt
#2 is \par  (from the blank line before \end{document})
As already commented since geometry is already parsing the argument as a key=value list there is no real advantage in parsing it all first using l3keys.

Right, but I want a user command rather than users actually calling the \geometry command directly.

can functions defined by \cs_new_protected:Nn \lenes:nn take key-value pairs as arguments?  If so, how is it done ?

@Bulldrive I already showed you how to provide a user command that uses geometry internally, but you ignore all previous answers, it seems. For your second comment obviously you can pass the argument of the command to a keyval parser whether it's defined by \cs_new_protected:Nn  or \def or \newcommand makes no difference, you already show \keys_set:nn {kvi_lenes} {#2}

Are you referring to \define@key{Gm}{mig}[true]{% \Gm@defbylen{paperwidth}{13cm}% ?

Would you pass key-value pairs as \lenes { left=21pt, top=21pt, bottom=21pt } with the function defined as \cs_new_protected:Nn \lenes:n ?
